# MySQL, selecting rows based on date column

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with two columns, like:

```
X         Date
A         2017-08-10
B         2016-12-19         
C         2017-06-13
D         2017-07-20
E         2017-07-14
```

I would like to avoid selecting data which is more than one week older than the data in a row with X=D.
I tried some queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date < (SELECT Date FROM table where X='D') - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

but it isn't work for me. 
The output should be like:

```
X         Date
A         2017-08-10
D         2017-07-20
E         2017-07-14
```

I'm close to solve this problem I think but a little help can be significant for me.

Comment: Come on. Try just a little bit harder.

Comment: @chirag satapara It was deleted I see

Comment: Don't use `table` as table name. Or at least use backtics. Your query is is very close to the solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06971/3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fish

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.date - INTERVAL 1 WEEK < x.date
   AND y.x = 'd';
```

Comment: I've got error after trying this query: Unknown column 'y.date' in 'on clause', of course I change columns' names

Comment: You've made some error in transcription. I can't see your query, so I can't say what that error is.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
Date > (SELECT DATE_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)  FROM table where X='D')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Date > (SELECT DATE_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  FROM table where X='D')
```

You can check here [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ee50/2)

Try above query.

Comment: Figure out an answer, and then post an answer.

Comment: Still having an error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WEEK' at line 1

Comment: I think the date should be ">" to last week not "<"

Comment: Now it's: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @JeffTheKiller Yes that make no impact on your answer.

Comment: @SagarGangwal Ok but I haven't got any return table now

Comment: @JeffTheKiller I had tried same it's working fine for me.
You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ee50/1